# PHP Xero API is creating duplicate overpayment entries (BankTransaction)

Tags: php, wordpress, xero-api

We are creating overpayments via the PHP Xero API.
In some cases, the overpayments are being duplicated.
Here is the code we are using:

```
<?php
    $endpoint = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/BankTransactions';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Xero-tenant-id: " . $xero_access['tenant_id'],
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $xero_access['token'],
    );

    $postFields = array(
        "Type" => "RECEIVE-OVERPAYMENT",
        'Contact' => ['ContactID' => $contactID],
        'BankAccount' => ['accountID' => $xero_settings['account_id']],
        'LineAmountTypes' => 'NoTax',
        'LineItems' => [0 => [
            'Description' => 'Customer Credit',
            'LineAmount' => $price
        ]]
    );

    try {
        $ch = @curl_init();
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        $response = @curl_exec($ch);

        $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        error_log($status_code);
        error_log($response);
    } finally {
        @curl_close($ch);
    }
?>
```

I am not quite sure why the transactions are being duplicated or even if it is a network issue, or something in the code above.

Is there a way to make these API calls unique and make sure a request is not sent twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you raise a case with [Xero Support](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/) and include:
Your client id, the name of the connect tenant, the date and time of a call with duplication (and your timezone), the details of the overpayment eg the contact name, date and amount